# Не получается добавить миниатюру в пост Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Настраиваю дочернюю тему от `Cherry Framework`, при создании новых записей, страниц не получается задать миниатюру - даёт выбрать картинку, выбираю, а дальше выбранная картинка не задается.

Права на папку `uploads` выставил 777, добавил в тему поддержку миниатюр на всякий случай.

Думал в браузере дело - через другие тоже самое. Поменял другую тему - тоже не помогло (не от Cherry, а родная от CMS).

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?